# Fetch Current image from horizontol scroll bar android

Tags: java, android, imageview, horizontalscrollview

I am trying to make a simple image gallery through which I can set wallpaper; I am using the below code to fetch the files from download folder and display it in scroll view.

I am able to do that, but now I want to fetch the currently displayed image so that I can set that image as wallpaper.

Below is the code I have for my activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 LinearLayout myGallery;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myGallery = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mygallery);

        String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment
          .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
          .getAbsolutePath();

        String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath ;

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), targetPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);

        File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();
        for (File file : files){
         myGallery.addView(insertPhoto(file.getAbsolutePath()));

        }    
    }

    View insertPhoto(String path){
     Bitmap bm = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(path, 520, 520);

     LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
     layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(550, 550));//Size of view
     layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

     ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
     imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(520, 520));
     imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
     imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);

     layout.addView(imageView);
     return layout;
    }

    public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
     Bitmap bm = null;

     // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
     final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
     options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
     BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

     // Calculate inSampleSize
     options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

     // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
     options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
     bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options); 

     return bm;  
    }

    public int calculateInSampleSize(

     BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
     // Raw height and width of image
     final int height = options.outHeight;
     final int width = options.outWidth;
     int inSampleSize = 1;

     if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
      if (width > height) {
       inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);   
      } else {
       inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);   
      }   
     }

     return inSampleSize;   
    }

}
```

Please tell me how I can fetch the image which is currently displayed in the scroll view.

Thanks
Aman

Comment: Any help over this...?

Answer (score 0):

its been 5 months yet not answered, but i think i will try to answer it.
I think you need a custom view ie. with canvas. create a canvas and then create a bitmap in canvas. After that when you get a bitmap from linear layout in the form of URI, in your code a method decodeSampledBitmapFromUri you are getting a bitmap, simply assign the bitmap to the created bitmap on the canvas.